# Why is the new chrome webdriver suspiciously dumping my cookies?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, chrome-web-driver

I updated my nuget package "Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver by jsakamoto" to version 117.0.5938.9200

Now when I create the driver to control chrome.

It dumps my browser's cookies into sqlite files called "C" and "C-journal":

[image]

The path of the files created are:

`D:\my-programs\C`

`D:\my-programs\C-journal`

My program resides in:

`D:\my-programs\C#\my-thing\my-thing\bin\Debug\my-thing.exe`

My chrome profile resides in:

`D:\my-programs\C#\my-thing\my-thing\bin\Debug\my-chrome-profile`

I set a breakpoint and confirmed that the files are created when I execute this line:

`tempDriver = new ChromeDriver(service, chromeOptions);`

Here is a screenshot of the "C" file loaded into a sqlite viewer:

[image]

My cookies were never automatically dumped to file in previous versions of "Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver".

Is this something malicious?

Recently the chrome driver executable was no longer being provided by chromium.org and provided new json endpoints for updating. Dunno if that is related to this issue.

Edit: I renamed C# to Cz# and now the files created are called Cz and Cz-journal so thats probably how it picks the file name.

Edit2: The params

```
private IWebDriver CreateDriver()
{
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions;

    IWebDriver tempDriver = null;


    string uniqueId = "my-program-" + Environment.TickCount;

    string myExtensionPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\my-stuff\\my-extension";

    string extensionId = settings.GetValue("extension id");

    try
    {
        chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();

        if (cbHideBrowser.Checked == true)
        {
            chromeOptions.AddArgument("--window-position=-10000,0");
            chromeOptions.AddArgument("--window-size=1920,1080");
        }
        else
        {
            chromeOptions.AddArgument("--window-position=-1920,0");
            chromeOptions.AddArgument("--window-size=1920,1080");
        }

        chromeOptions.AddArgument(uniqueId);
        chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-infobars");
        chromeOptions.AddArgument("--user-data-dir=" + Path.GetFullPath("my-chrome-profile"));
        chromeOptions.AddArgument("--my-program");
        chromeOptions.AddArgument("--process-per-site");
        chromeOptions.AddArgument(@"--load-extension=" + myExtensionPath + "," + Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\uBlock-Origin-development-build_v1.24.5.4");
        chromeOptions.AddArgument(@"--allowlisted-extension-id=" + extensionId);

        chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.prompt_for_download", false);
        chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.directory_upgrade", true);
        chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\myfiles");

        chromeOptions.BinaryLocation = "C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe";

        ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();

        service.HideCommandPromptWindow = cbHideBrowser.Checked;

        tempDriver = new ChromeDriver(service, chromeOptions);
        
        if (cbHideBrowser.Checked == true)
        {
            processId = GetProcessIdByCommandLineArg(uniqueId);

            Process p = Process.GetProcessById(processId);

            ShowWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, 0);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception x)
    {

    }
    
    return tempDriver;
}
```

Comment: The location is a little odd, but it is normal for chromedriver to create a temporary directory for values saved during the session... it should delete that directory when you quit the driver.  (it may also copy existing files such as cookies when specifying a specific profile)  It's usually a folder with "scoped" in the name if I remember right... You should probably ditch the nuget package and test using the new built-in driver manager.

Comment: You should probably include your driver initialization code in your post.  There may be some settings in there which explain this.  ex: user-data-dir...

Comment: @pcalkins I added the init code. I've also tried this driver: https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/117.0.5938.149/win64/chromedriver-win64.zip but it still makes the files. The selenium-manager.exe is in my install folder, but I don't see how to use it via code. The C and C-journal files are not deleted upon `driver.Quit()`

Comment: Try without setting options and see if it still happens.  I suppose it could be that your setting a user-data-dir, but that would be deleted on quit... so maybe the extension you are including?  If it still happens without setting any chromeoptions then something else is happening.  (Just use  tempDriver = new ChromeDriver(); )

Comment: @pcalkins I tested it and it only creates those files when I specify the `--user-data-dir` flag.

Comment: @pcalkins  It creates those files when I pass the user data dir to chrome in the command prompt as well. So its not specific to selenium